# Scale up images in Bootstrap 3

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to scale up images in bootstrap 3?

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
> of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and
> height: auto; to the image so that it **scales nicely to the parent
> element**.

With the following code the image scales down well, but it's not get the parent div's size on larger screens.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" style="background:yellow">
        <div class="image-container" style="background:green">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do that? Demo: http://www.bootply.com/8uXBxX8Qjy

Answer (score 8):

You can set the image width to 100%.  The img-responsive sets max-width to 100%, the image itself will never be larger than it's actual dimensions.  Setting the width to 100% will force it to be the width of its parent regardless of its actually size, but be warned that this can sometimes cause images to become pixelated depending on the image size and how much it is being scaled to fit.

Comment: You want to also add height:auto; so the image doesn't get distorted: http://www.bootply.com/3JttHDROHJ

Comment: You can, but it's superfluous.  If you only define one (either height or width) on images it will retain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had this issue, I was using a theme based on Bootstrap 3.
I was using the theme in Wordpress live site.

**Problem**

The problem was that, image enclosed in `img` tag and which further was enclosed in Wordpress's own class defined for image. And the image not properly scaled.
Images having low width would fit inside the main `div`, in which the image was placed, some images having big width, going outside of the main article. And using such broken `CSS` functionalities is a havoc for my website. Until I found the solution.

**Solution**

Find which img tag is responsible for image scaling, you can test in Browser's inspect element, and find which tag is responsible for image scaling. And put the below code there and test. And your theme could have different tag responsible for `img` scaling property set with Bootstrap.

For mine it was :

```
img{
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

The theme already had, `img{vertical-align: middle}` present, so I tested for `width:100%` and the rest `CSS` rule, and it worked. Your theme could have some differnt CSS rule or tag set, find that and apply. But these two `rules` should be applied to scale image properly. Thanks @David Taiaroa for `height: auto` CSS rule